# how to show multiple colums on search for mudautocomplete component in mudblazor . example attached screenshot

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly, mudblazor

how to show multiple colums on search for  mudautocomplete component in mudblazor . example [image: attached screenshot]

do we need to do any customization ?. I am new to mudblazor.

any ideas or code snippets are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a custom solution with MudBlazor components for you on which you can expand. To play around with it check out this playground snippet: https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/GaQbvwPzyfOfrMyA

[image: custom autocomplete]

Here is the code:

```html
<div style="max-width:600px">
<MudTextField @bind-Value="SearchText" Placeholder="Type to search" Immediate="true" @onclick="@(()=>_isOpen=true)" @onkeydown="OnKeyDown"/>
<MudPopover Open="@_isOpen" MaxHeight="300" AnchorOrigin="@Origin.BottomCenter" 
    TransformOrigin="@Origin.TopCenter" RelativeWidth="true">
    <MudSimpleTable Style="overflow-x: auto;" Dense="true">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            @foreach (var h in headings)
            {
                <th>@h</th>
            }
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var row in rows.Where(x=>x.Contains(_searchText??"")))
        {
            <tr>
                @foreach (var x in row.Split())
                {
                    <td>@x</td>
                }
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
    </MudSimpleTable>
</MudPopover>    
</div>

@code {
    private bool _isOpen;
    private string _searchText;
    public string SearchText {
        get=>_searchText;
        set {
            if (_searchText==value)
                return;
            _searchText=value;
            _isOpen=true;   
            StateHasChanged();
        }
    }

    string[] headings = { "ID", "Name", "Email", "Gender", "IP Address" };
    string[] rows = {
        @"1 Krishna kpartner0@usatoday.com Male 28.25.250.202",
        @"2 Webb wstitle1@ning.com Male 237.168.134.114",
        @"3 Nathanil nneal2@cyberchimps.com Male 92.6.0.175",
        @"4 Adara alockwood3@patch.com Female 182.174.217.152",
        @"5 Cecilius cchaplin4@shinystat.com Male 195.124.144.18",
        @"6 Cicely cemerine9@soup.io Female 138.94.191.43",
    };

    private void OnKeyDown(KeyboardEventArgs args) {
        if (args.Key=="Enter")
            _isOpen=false;
    }
}
```

This snippet shows how you can create your own filtered dropdown. If you use MudTable instead of SimpleTable you can use the row click event to get the selected row and then you should practically have your fully working custom autocomplete.

Comment: thanks for answer. Is any way that we can achieve with mudautocomplete component. ?

Comment: no, because autocomplete shows a list. there is no way to transform a list into a table

Comment: i see a property called ItemTemplate in MudAutocomplete. Does that help us getting data in table format?. what's your thought on it.@henon

Comment: It lets you style the list row of an autocomplete item. But even if you style it like a table row you still have no header. The snippet I posted is pretty much the same as the autocomplete does internally. You just have to use a MudTable instead of MudSimpleTable to get the selected item on row click and you have an autocomplete with a table instead of a list.

Comment: thanks. do we have any default feature to show loader while loading data in autocomplete. ?

Comment: There is a PR in the works but it looks the original autor is not completing it. You might take his code, complete it and start a new PR to get it merged sooner: https://github.com/MudBlazor/MudBlazor/pull/3096

PS: if my answer answers your question please mark it as the answer. Thanks

Comment: Btw: a loading bar has since been added to autocomplete